# How to send a post request to a 3rd party application in django?

Tags: python, django, api, django-views, webhooks

i have made an api where i am receiving an api request about the successful payment now in the same code i have to make a post request to an other external application to notify about the payment with a json data in request body.so i was trying to use python's requests to accomplish this, please help me if there is any other way

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def cashfree_request(request):                
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        data=request.POST.dict()
        print(data)
        payment_gateway_order_identifier= data['orderId'] 
        amount = data['orderAmount']
       
        order=Orders.objects.get(payment_gateway_order_identifier=payment_gateway_order_identifier)
        payment = Payments(orders=order,amount=amount,)
        payment.save()
 
        URL = "" # external application url where webhook needs to send

        request_data ={
                       order:{
                       'id':order.id,
                       'payment_collection_status': transaction_status,
                       'payment_collection_message': transaction_message
                                         }
                                   }
         json_data = json.dumps(request_data)
         response = requests.post(url = URL, data = json_data)
         return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK
```

Comment: Is it not working?

Comment: When you're trying to send requests using Django/Python, best approach would be requests module.